# Android Studio not recognizing Class "ILineDataSet" from MPAndroid Chart library

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to create a line graph. I found a tutorial from the following site which I have been following:
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data

The problem I am having is with this line of code:

```
List<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
```

Android studio does not seem to recognize the type "ILineDataSet" and as a result is preventing me from proceeding any further in completing this task.

It has offered solutions to resolve it, which are:
Create Class
Create Enum
Create Inner Class
Create Interface

All of which I do not think will solve the issue as I assume the library has already configured this but for some reason its not being picked up by android studio.

Could someone direct me as to how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the Activity you're trying to use ILineDataSet in? Could just be a missing import?

Answer (score 0):

I'm so stupid.

Library wasnt updated.

Please ignore this

Answer (score 0):

I was going to ask if you added:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
}
```

To your gradle.build